# Complexity of inbuild functions of javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

i am using one function and i really want to know the time and space complexity of the function below.

```
function containCommonElements(array1, array2) {
   return array1.some(item=> array2.includes(item))
}
```

and do tell what is the complexity of inbuild functions and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native javascript functions are not implemented in javascript, so it's a bit hard to look under the hood to find the actual information.

However I found [this repository](https://gist.github.com/alexhawkins/28aaf610a3e76d8b8264) showing how to implement a few native functions, including `Array.prototype.some`:

```
Array.prototype.mySome = function(callback, context) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (callback.call(context, this[i], i, this))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Which would mean that `Array.prototype.some` has a complexity of `O(n)`

We can make an educated guess that `Array.prototype` has probably a similar complexity.

That gives us a complexity of `O(n²)` for your function.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Array.some` and `Array.includes` are linear search functions `O(n)`. Since you use one inside another resulting complexity: `O(array1.length * array2.length)`.